# Do event after click on ImageView which is inside of the tableView which contains observableArray

Tags: java, javafx

I have a class (TaskInOurProgram) which contains ImageView in constructer. 
Here is a little code snipped - declaration and then constructer:

```
private ImageView closeTask;
private ImageView pauseTask;
private final Image pauseImage = new Image("file:images/pause.png");
private final Image closeImage = new Image("file:images/close.png");

public TaskInOurProgram(String name, String configName, String extensionOfTheFile) {
    this.nameOfTheFile = name;
    this.configName = configName;
    this.extensionOfTheFile = extensionOfTheFile;
    this.closeTask = new ImageView();
    closeTask.setImage(closeImage);
    this.pauseTask = new ImageView();
    pauseTask.setImage(pauseImage);       
}
```

Then I have a observableArrayList which contains many of these TaskInOurProgram objects.

```
private ObservableList<TaskInOurProgram> tasksInTheTableView = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

I have a tableView which displays this list of objects. So then it looks like this.

[image]

Object are not there from the beginning, they need to be added by clicking at button ADD TASK and because it is observableList, it will show this "tasks" immediately after adding.

WHAT I NEED: What I need is to create method inside of the controller which will do something after click on "pause" ImageView. I really do not know how to do it, I was thinking about listeners somehow. And before that I need to put click event on imageView.

Can you guys, please, help me with this? Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a Button with a Graphic instead of a plain ImageView. That way you can use the [`Button.setOnAction()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#setOnAction-javafx.event.EventHandler-) method.

Where you are currently defining your ImageView, change it to the following:

```
this.pauseTask = new Button("", new ImageView(pauseImage));
this.pauseTask.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        pause();
    }
});
```

You can define a method somewhere else in your program, something like this:

```
private void pause() {
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setOnMouseClicked()` method for `imageView` to handle click events.

```
pauseTask.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<Event>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(Event event)
            {
                pauseTask();
            }
        });
```

Then you can handle it in other method

```
void pauseTask()
{

}
```